# InvalidStateError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 11 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, indexeddb

The following code:

```
request=window.webkitIndexedDB.open('tileStore');
```

yields a request with error: exception 11.  Open works for other databases.  Additionally,

```
request=window.webkitIndexedDB.deleteDatabase('tileStore')
```

correctly yields a `IDBVersionChangeRequest`with error 11.

How do I reset the db's state without opening or deleting it?

Comment: Whats the different btw those 2 lines of code?

Comment: oops, copy error.  fixed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to delete the database your self manually. I wrote a [post](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2011/11/indexed-db-deleting-your-database.html) about it a while ago. If the spec is correctly implemented an exception with errorCode 11 should mean you have a quota err. Meaning you reached the maximum file size for the database.